# Volume of the solid with circular cross section

Tags: calculus, geometry, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

> Each plane perpendicular to the x-axis intersects a certain solid in a circular cross section whose diameter lies in the xy-plane and extends from $x^2 = 4y$ to $y^2 = 4x$. The solid lies between the points of intersection of these curves. Find its volume

**My approach**

$\mathcal The$ $\mathcal graph$
[image: the graph]

$y^2=4x \Rightarrow y = 2\sqrt{x} = f(x)$

$x^2=4y \Rightarrow y = {x^2\over 4} = g(x)$

$\pmb The$ $\pmb Solid$
[image: the solid]

Points of intersection are (0,0) and (4,4)
In [0,4] , f(x) > g(x)

So radius at x ,
$2r = f(x) - g(x)$

$r = \sqrt{x} - {x^2\over 8}$

Volume of disc
$dv = \pi r^2dx$

$= \pi [x + {x^4\over 64} - {x^2\sqrt{x}\over 4}]dx$

$\int_{0}^{V}dv = \int_{0}^{4} \pi [x + {x^4\over 64} - {x^2\sqrt{x}\over 4}]dx$

$= \pi [ {x^2\over 2} + {x^5\over 5×64} - {x^{7\over 2}\over 14} ]_{0}^{4}$

$= {72\pi \over 35}$

**I don't know whether my approach and steps are correct or not**
*pointing out the error in my solution and suggesting the right one would be of much help*

Answer (score 1):

Your integration/thinking process is correct however you made minor calculation errors along the way. For starters when writing g(x), you simplify wrong by dividing by 2 instead of 4. So it should have been $g(x) = x^2/4$. Additionally, when writing the radius in terms of $x$ as you miswrite the $g(x)$ function again as $(x/2)/2$ when in reality it should have been $(x^2/4)/2 = x^2/8$

Comment: Yeah I saw that and have  now rectified it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Is the answer you get after changing those values still wrong?

Comment: Another issue was when you square your radius x^4/64 should be positive although you later fix that in your problem

Comment: I don't know. My books does not has answer for this question

Comment: yeah, it was a typing mistake

Comment: Alright, your thinking process is correct which is what matters imo so I think its fine. I haven't checked your numbers tho

Comment: Yep it's correct, I checked it on calculator.